# Spring controller not recognized

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm trying to set up a simple spring mvc application using class configuration and without web.xml.
For some reason it appears that my controller is not being properly scanned during the component scan.

My projet is as following:

```
src/main/java
 -org.webapp.mvc
   -config
     WebAppInitializer
     WebConfig
   -controllers
     SimpleController

src/main/webapp
   -hello.jsp
   -index.jsp
```

WebAppInitializer:

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException     {
    WebApplicationContext context = getContext(); //spring configuration  context
    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher =  servletContext.addServlet("DispatcherServlet", new DispatcherServlet(context));
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping("/*"); //URL mapping
}

private AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext getContext() {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new  AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    context.setConfigLocation("org.webapp.mvc.config.WebConfig");
    return context;
}
```

}

WebConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "org.webapp.mvc.controllers")
public class WebConfig {

}
```

SimpleController:

```
@Controller
public class SimpleController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/greeting")
public String test(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("greeting", "Hello World");
    return "hello.jsp";
}

}
```

Supposedly 'localhost:8080/project/greeting' should serve 'hello.jsp', but it shows that there's no metching mapping for the URI:

```
03:22:15.385 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet -     DispatcherServlet with name 'DispatcherServlet' processing GET request for     [/project/greeting]
03:22:15.385 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] WARN  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/project/greeting] in DispatcherServlet with name 'DispatcherServlet'
03:22:15.385 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

[update]
Adding debug:

```
    03:22:08.824 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'DispatcherServlet': initialization started
    03:22:08.828 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Unable to locate MultipartResolver with name 'multipartResolver': no multipart request handling provided
    03:22:08.829 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver'
    03:22:08.872 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver'
    03:22:08.872 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Unable to locate LocaleResolver with name 'localeResolver': using default [org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver@587b4b84]
    03:22:08.874 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.FixedThemeResolver'
    03:22:08.880 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.FixedThemeResolver'
    03:22:08.880 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Unable to locate ThemeResolver with name 'themeResolver': using default [org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.FixedThemeResolver@7e02662a]
    03:22:08.886 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping'
    03:22:08.906 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Looking for URL mappings in application context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sat Apr 18 03:22:08 IDT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
    03:22:08.907 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor': no URL paths identified
    03:22:08.907 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor': no URL paths identified
    03:22:08.907 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor': no URL paths identified
    03:22:08.907 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor': no URL paths identified
    03:22:08.907 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor': no URL paths identified
    03:22:08.907 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor': no URL paths identified
    03:22:08.907 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'environment': no URL paths identified
    03:22:08.907 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'systemProperties': no URL paths identified
    03:22:08.907 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'systemEnvironment': no URL paths identified
    03:22:08.907 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'servletContext': no URL paths identified
    03:22:08.907 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'contextParameters': no URL paths identified
    03:22:08.907 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'contextAttributes': no URL paths identified
    03:22:08.907 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'messageSource': no URL paths identified
    03:22:08.907 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'applicationEventMulticaster': no URL paths identified
    03:22:08.907 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'lifecycleProcessor': no URL paths identified
    03:22:08.907 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping'
    03:22:08.908 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping'
    03:22:08.916 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.a.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Looking for URL mappings in application context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sat Apr 18 03:22:08 IDT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
    03:22:08.918 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.a.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor': no URL paths identified
    03:22:08.918 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.a.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor': no URL paths identified
    03:22:08.918 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.a.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor': no URL paths identified
    03:22:08.918 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.a.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor': no URL paths identified
    03:22:08.918 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.a.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor': no URL paths identified
    03:22:08.918 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.a.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor': no URL paths identified
    03:22:08.918 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.a.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'environment': no URL paths identified
    03:22:08.918 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.a.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'systemProperties': no URL paths identified
    03:22:08.918 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.a.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'systemEnvironment': no URL paths identified
    03:22:08.918 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.a.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'servletContext': no URL paths identified
    03:22:08.918 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.a.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'contextParameters': no URL paths identified
    03:22:08.918 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.a.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'contextAttributes': no URL paths identified
    03:22:08.918 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.a.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'messageSource': no URL paths identified
    03:22:08.918 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.a.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'applicationEventMulticaster': no URL paths identified
    03:22:08.918 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.a.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'lifecycleProcessor': no URL paths identified
    03:22:08.918 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping'
    03:22:08.918 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - No HandlerMappings found in servlet 'DispatcherServlet': using default
    03:22:08.921 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter'
    03:22:08.924 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter'
    03:22:08.926 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter'
    03:22:08.928 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter'
    03:22:08.930 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter'
    03:22:09.049 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter'
    03:22:09.049 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - No HandlerAdapters found in servlet 'DispatcherServlet': using default
    03:22:09.053 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver'
    03:22:09.063 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver'
    03:22:09.064 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver'
    03:22:09.069 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver'
    03:22:09.070 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver'
    03:22:09.085 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver'
    03:22:09.085 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - No HandlerExceptionResolvers found in servlet 'DispatcherServlet': using default
    03:22:09.088 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator'
    03:22:09.093 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator'
    03:22:09.093 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Unable to locate RequestToViewNameTranslator with name 'viewNameTranslator': using default [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator@18abaed]
    03:22:09.096 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver'
    03:22:09.114 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver'
    03:22:09.114 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - No ViewResolvers found in servlet 'DispatcherServlet': using default
    03:22:09.119 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager'
    03:22:09.128 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager'
    03:22:09.128 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Unable to locate FlashMapManager with name 'flashMapManager': using default [org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager@726c87e9]
    03:22:09.128 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Published WebApplicationContext of servlet 'DispatcherServlet' as ServletContext attribute with name [org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.DispatcherServlet]
    03:22:09.128 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'DispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 304 ms
    03:22:09.128 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Servlet 'DispatcherServlet' configured successfully
```

Comment: Do you have spring configured in your web.xml?

Comment: Post the startup messages. At DEBUG, the dispatcher servlet will log all its mappings.

Comment: @redge The OP already included the annotation-based configuration.

Comment: There is no web.xml, I'm using WebAppInitializer instead, which points to WebConfig which contains the spring configuration.

Comment: @chrylis I've added the debug log, I couldn't post all of it due to character limitation, let me know if I missed the relevant part.

Comment: Which container are you using?

Comment: Okay, you're looking for the annotation handler, where it's saying it's not finding anything. Your controller does not appear to be instantiated, and I'd add a constructor that logs when the controller is created and figure out why it's not being called.

Comment: @xerx593 I'm using tomcat 8

Comment: @chrylis I've added a constructor to the controller with a log and indeed it doesn't seem that controller is initiated, but I dont understand the reason behind this. WebAppInitializer sets config location as: "org.webapp.mvc.config.WebConfig", and WebConfig states:@ComponentScan(basePackages = "org.webapp.mvc.controllers") which is the package containing the controller.

Comment: Try adding `@RequestMapping("/")` to your controller class

Comment: @EnableAutoConfiguration !?

Comment: dispatcher.addMapping("/*"); -> "/"  (as in examples)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to WebConfig

```
    @Bean
    public UrlBasedViewResolver jspResolver(){
        System.out.println("in WebConfig jspResolver");
        UrlBasedViewResolver urlBasedViewResolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        urlBasedViewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        urlBasedViewResolver.setPrefix("/");
        urlBasedViewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return urlBasedViewResolver;
    }
```

this will allow the mapping of JSPs as JSPs instead of expecting a controller with such a mapping

Change the following line in WebAppInitializer

```
    dispatcher.addMapping("/*"); //URL mapping
```

to

```
    dispatcher.addMapping("/"); //URL mapping
```

This will make this servlet the default mapping instead of using it for everything.

Change SimpleController to return `"hello"` instead of `"hello.jsp"` so the ViewResolver will create the correct path.

Make sure that maven resource javax.servlet:jstl:1.2 is packaged into the class or installed into Tomcat as it doesn't come as standard.

With these changes it works in my environment

BTW : I used spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE
I also just ran it with spring-webmvc-3.2.13.RELEASE

I have added my Pom here with the minimal set of dependencies I needed to run the code.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>annotationConfig1</groupId>
    <artifactId>annotationConfig1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.13.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: For some reason WebConfig doesn't seem to load at all, the println from the  UrlBasedViewResolver bean you suggested is never printed. I've double checked the packeges names over and over, and there's no mistakes there. I've uploaded the project to github in case you'll have a chance to take a look, maybe I'm missing on somthing else. [link](https://github.com/anhermon/springMVC)

Comment: I have never used spring-boot before so I could not get it to work I have included my pom contents. I installed Tomcat as a server under eclipse and ran in that.

Comment: Thank you so much, I've removed spring boot (I've built this project based on the spring starter project so it was there by default), I've configured the pom manually and now it works properly. thanks!.

Comment: Ive upgraded my pom to javaee 7 and it still works too.

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/greeting")
public String test(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("greeting", "Hello World");
    return "hello.jsp";
}
```

What I can see in your code that, you have added request mapping with "/greeting", so the url should be like : ***hostname:port/greeting***

if you are running in your local machine with embedded server or with the IDE e.g IntelliJ IDEA, try:

http://localhost:8080/greeting

in case, you're running different server, say tomcat, rename your war as a ROOT.war and put it webapps folder and above url will work.

If you don't rename it, and keep the project.war, then you will able to access by

http://localhost:8080/project/greeting

Comment: I'm using tomcat in eclipse, so the project name is part of the url path. from server.xml: <Context docBase="project" path="/project" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:project"/></Host>

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your controller class is in the org.webapp.mvc.controllers package, from the logs, it doesn't look like the scan is picking up the class and it's URL mapping